# Why is getElementsByClassName returning undefined in React funcitonal component?

Tags: react-functional-component, getelementsbyclassname

In one of my functional components in an application using React.js, calling getElementsByClassName returns 'undefined', when clearly, there is a section tag with the className.

```
const ExpansionView = (props) => {

const validExpansion = [
    "Classic", "Naxxramas", "Goblins vs Gnomes",
];

//create a function that will filter by validExpansion and create an Expansion component
const expansionGenerator = (props) => {
    **// the line below returns undefined!**
    const expansionViewTag = document.getElementsByClassName('expansionView')[0];

    for (let i = 0; i < validExpansion.length; i += 1) {
        expansionViewTag.appendChild(
            <Expansion specificExpansion={props.expansion[validExpansion[i]]} selectExpansion={props.selectExpansion}/>
        )
    }
    return 
}

return(
    // clearly, here is a section tag with the className.
    <section className='expansionView'>
       {expansionGenerator(props)}
    </section>
)
```

}

export default ExpansionView;

Please take a look. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This will render `undefined` when the component is mounted but if you rerender you component then it will return you with the result you are expecting because on initial load your function gets executed before react attaches `expansionView` on the DOM. You can also make use of refs or useEffect to get the dom after they are rendered but not so useful in your case.
For your problem, you can simply use react components to render your filter components.

```
 const App = () => {

   const ExpansionComponent = () => {
     // props is shared between App and ExpansionComponent because of closure
     // Do you filters
     return <FilteredComponents /> // example

   }  

   return (
     <div className="your-class"> 
       <ExpansionComponent />
    </div>
   )

 }
```